# Erro na configuração do ambiente

Tags: java, primefaces, wildfly

Estou usando java JPA, com Wildfly  e Primefaces e o banco estou usando o Mysql.

Tenho todas as camadas ja configuradas (view(xhtml),DAO,Entidade,MB).
O datasouce do wildfly está configurado corretamente, mantendo a comunicação com o banco 100%.

Quando eu vou rodar o projeto ele acusa "404 - Not Found" e aparenemente o console nao exibe nada de anormal.
Creio que seja erro na configuração de ambiente mas nao estou conseguindo identificar.

Eu não sei verificar qual é a versao do JSF, sou novo na programação aqui.
Segue o meu web.xml:

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esta é a minha ultima linha do log quando tento rodar:

> WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
>         service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.ExampleDS (missing) dependents: [service jboss.naming.context.java.module.solicitacaoAtendimento.solicitacaoAtendimento.DefaultDataSource]

Comment: Bom, já que vc acha que é configuração de ambiente, publique a pergunta com todas as configurações, incluindo o a estrutura do seu projeto, com o nome das views  (.xhtml) para melhor análise, mas de ante mão, veja se está tudo ok, com a URI que vc está tentando acessar.

Answer (score 0):

Pedro

- Qual **versão do JSF** você está usando?
- Poderia compartilhar a configuração do seu **web.xml** ?
- Veja se de fato nenhum **erro** está aparecendo nos **logs da aplicação**, pois pode estar ocorrendo por exemplo **conflito de bibliotecas** da sua aplicação com as do **Wildfly**.

O erro ainda poderia estar relacionado a configuração do contexto da sua aplicação no arquivo web.xml e ainda pode estar associado a estrutura de diretórios que você está usando na aplicação.

Exemplo de acesso e configuração

```
http://localhost:8080/NomeProjeto/index.xhtml
```

Estrutura de diretórios do projeto na sua IDE

```
NomeProjeto
 |-- Java Resources
 |    `-- src
 |         `-- br.com.app.controle
 |              `-- MyBean.java
 |-- resources
 |-- JavaScript Resources
 |-- build
 `-- WebContent
      |-- META-INF
      |-- WEB-INF
      |    |-- faces-config.xml
      |    `-- web.xml
      |-- index.xhtml
      `-- pagina.xhtml
```